# Perl on Windows translates my newlines to CRLF

Tags: windows, perl

`print FILEHANDLE;` - when run from a Windows box - always converts a trailing `\n` into `\r\n` - resulting in a DOS formatted file.  The difference between a DOS and a UNIX file is that in UNIX, the last character of each line is \n, whereas in Windows it is `\r\n`.  I have tried changing the line termination character `$\ = "\n";` but the print command still does the conversion to DOS format.  This only occurs on Windows boxes.

Comment: `man perlio` is useful reading.

Comment: What was this question closed!?!

Comment: `open(my $fh, '>:raw', ...)` or `binmode($fh);`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like how Perl decides to output your data, you can change it. In the three-argument `open`, it looks like this:

```
open my $fh, '>:raw', $filename;
```

Or, if you already have the filehandle, you can use `binmode`:

```
binmode $fh, ':raw';
binmode $fh;          # :raw is the default
```

The output depends on various IO "layers", each of which gets to stick their dirty fingers into your data before it is output. The [perlio](https://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html) docs have the list. There's a `:crlf` layer that turns unix line endings, and you are probably getting it by default. Note that changing the output record separator is something that happens at the `print` level, but there are deeper layers that can still do their work.

Comment: So many thanks - I now have a UNIX format file - 'raw' did work - and it was not mentioned in my Perl book

Comment: Which Perl book? It's not something that we get into with [Learning Perl](https://www.learning-perl.com), but maybe we should.

Comment: the book i am using is old - perl 5 - interactive course - Jon Orwant - waite group press

Comment: So much good practice has changed since then, especially in Perls v5.6, v5.8, and then v5.10. Jon's book is so old that people born after its publication can almost rent cars.